# MySQL -> How to get the one row previous to a specific row

Tags: mysql, sql

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 100 |
| 00:01 | 101 |
| 00:02 | 102 |
| 01:03 | 103 |
| 02:04 | 104 |
| 03:05 | 105 |
| 03:10 | 106 |

Say, I have a mysql table with the above stucture indexed on the time column.

How can I get the first row just before a specific timestamp. For instance I should to be able to read the row of **[02:04 : 104]** if I want to get a timestamp before **02:30**.

Also since the time doesn't increase consistently I cannot fetch by just decreasing by one minute.

One way I know of is by ordering rows by descending and limit by 1, but it seems this performs an index range scan which would be costly as the number of rows increases. Is there any way to get the value as constant time operation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `LIMIT` query:

```sql
SELECT time, value
FROM yourTable
WHERE time < '02:30'
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The above query can benefit from the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (time, value);
```

This should let MySQL rapidly find the record of interest, in logarithmic time, and return it.  The index also covers the `value` column, so this can be said to be a *covering* index.

Comment: Yes, but the problem with this is it seems to perform a scan for all rows before 02:30 and then returns the first row after descending. This will be quite intensive if there are lots of rows in the table.

Comment: @VikrantPradhan There is no avoiding the sort AFAIK.  Check my updated answer for an index option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it in constant time. I believe you should create the previous time point using `LAG`, add an index, then filter with a `WHERE` statement. Out of curiosity and since you have an index on `time`, does this run faster than the `LIMIT` query?

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT time,
      value,
      LAG(time) OVER(ORDER by time) AS prev_time
   FROM input_table
   -- Try to add a WHERE statement here to limit the number of rows selected (since you have an index on time). That would make things faster of course.
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE '02:30' BETWEEN prev_time and time
```